# Error parsing Spring boot's Stacktrace log in Fluentd by using Multiline parser

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, fluentd

I was trying to use multiline parser of Fluentd to parse Spring boot application log before submitting to Elasticsearch. It was working properly both Stacktrace and others logs. if I read the log from file.

[image]

But when I use Fluentd to directly receive the log from that Spring boot container by using logging driver instead, there was a error parsing stacktrace log but others were okay.

[image]

I found out on Fluentd documentation page that other input plugins except in_tail don't work with `multiline`. So, I'm not sure how I can achieve this. I saw someone mention about 
fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions or fluent-plugin-concat but I cannot find the good example how to use it or how I parse the log after concatenate the multiline.